# Unity mesh collider isn't colliding with other objects, 2D game

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, collider

I've made a mesh from an SVG in Blender and converted it to a mesh. I then put it into Unity, to put a collider on it, the mesh does not collide with anything, even with convex ticked.

Here is my collider:

[image: Collider]

And here is my mesh in Blender (blue is the outside of the mesh):

[image: Mesh in blender]

What the convex collider looks like:

[image: Convex collider]

Can someone tell me why the collider is not working?
Cheers!

Comment: Did you have `Rigidbody` on the game object? And make sure your collider setting meet the `Collision action matrix` section in https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html

Comment: I have a rigidbody2D component on my player but not on my mesh gameObjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MeshCollider](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MeshCollider.html) is implemented in the 3D Physics engine and therefore incompatible with the 2D Physics engine. They simply don't interact.

What you probably want to use instead is the [PolygonCollider2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html)

Comment: Thank you, the polygon collider needed a script that I found on the unity answers, here is the link: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1484280/generate-2d-polygon-collider-from-3d-mesh.html

Answer (score 0):

When working with Colliders and 2D, make sure you have the following:

- RigidBody2D
- Collider2D

In addition a Mesh Collider is a 3D implementation. If you want the 2D equivalent of a Mesh Collider in 2D, use a `Polygon Collider 2D` instead.

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. The game is 2D yes, I know that you need rigidbody2D. But my mesh collider isn't working

Comment: Mesh collider is a 3D implementation so it won't work. Remove it and add `Polygon Collider 2D` which is a mesh collider but for 2D